# Get to a XAML control by name in a DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, listview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a ListView with a custom DataTemplate.

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SECTextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I select myTextBox for the selected item when the user changes the item in the listview?

Thanks

This is using a windows 8.1 store application.

Comment: What do you mean by Select?

Comment: as in I want to do myTextBox.Text="this is what I want to do"

Answer (score 0):

One way is Tapped event on your SecTextBox, or Grid....

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SECTextBox x:Name="myTextBox" 
                    Text="Test"
                    Tapped="HandleOnTapped"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>





 private void HandleOnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       SECTextBox txt = (SECTextBox)sender;
       // now you have your textbox

    }
```